# How to INNER JOIN only one row from second table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by, inner-join

I have a issue joining only one row from the second table

statement:

```
 SELECT ART.*, EAN.*
   FROM ART,EAN 
  WHERE ART.ARTNR = ean.unit_artnr
    AND ean.typ = 'LE4';
```

TABLE EAN has sometimes 2 entries and so i get my

> ART.ARTNR

doubled in the output.

i cant figure a way out to only include one row from EAN

i tried with group by but that does not do the trick because i need the * selects

sample data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3f0a57795fdeb6745155a6e823643c40

now if i execute my statement it shows 2 times ART.ARTNR 1234556  and 2 times 23455 but this should not be the case each ARTNR should be shown once

Comment: You can use the analytic function row_number() to label the rows from your second table and then you can join where the row number = 1.

Comment: use `distinct` in select

Comment: @MuhammadWaheed this does not work, because there are multiple entries in ART and i need all of them but if i join EAN like i did it shows some ART entries doubled because there are 2 entries in EAN

Comment: Your sample data does not correspond to the SQL, where is ean.typ?

Comment: corrected sorry

Comment: Again I don't see I ean how two ean.typ exists. Please use some real data, fictitious data without any planning how to stage them will not get us anywhere

Comment: the typ is not necessary in this case..

Comment: In your sample you dont even have the column `ARTNR` in your table `EAN`, but you list `ARTNR` and `UNIT_ARTNR` both as columns in your initial statement. And which row from EAN should be prefered? They're not equal

Comment: also not needed . edited post

Comment: You could use `CROSS APPLY` provided your Oracle version features it. Which Oracle version are you using?  Which EAN row do you want in case there are multiple matches?

Comment: On a sidenote: Comma-separated joins were made redundant in standard SQL in 1992. They are prone to errors and can make maintenance more difficult. You shouldn't use them anymore. Use ANSI joins instead as shown in the better answers.

Comment: yeah the statement is the one that is currently in the program i will make it ANSI friendly. i am using oracle 11. in this case it doesnt matter which one because there are always 2 identical ones in the fields i need.  i can eliminate them because these are customer datas that vary in fields i am not using. so just one of two which one doesnt matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ART.*, EANC.*
from ART
  inner join (select EAN.EAN_ID,
                     EAN.EAN,
                     EAN.UNIT_ARTNR,
                     EAN.TYP,
                     row_number() over (partition by EAN.UNIT_ARTNR order by EAN.EAN_ID) as "ROWNR" 
              from EAN) EANC on ART.ARTNR = EANC.UNIT_ARTNR
where EANC.ROWNR = 1
```

The partition-by was right from @Zaynul's answer, but he used the wrong column to partition over.

In my example I order the rows of `EAN` by `EAN.EAN_ID`. If you want some other order, change it here.

The result in your example is (you can omit the ROWNR)

```
ARTNR   EAN_ID  EAN         UNIT_ARTNR  TYP     ROWNR
23455   5       7771234568  23455       LE4     1
1234556 1       1234        1234556     LE4     1
```

Comment: what if the EAN table has like 20 collumns, can i make the subquery select at the inner join like " select * " ?

Comment: EAN.* should work just the same like all the single columns listed. `select EAN.*, row_number()...`. I like to only select what's needed and therefor write all columns explicitely.

Answer (score 2):

avoid coma separated join use explicit join and analytic function `row_number()`

```
  SELECT art.*, EAN.*, 
   EAN.unit_artnr "EAN_ARTNR"
   FROM art join 
   (
   select ean_id,ean,unit_artnr,typ,
   row_number() over(partition by typ order by ean_id)rn from ean
   ) EAN on ART.ARTNR = ean.unit_artnr
   WHERE 
    EAN.typ = 'LE4' and EAN.rn=1
```

Comment: i get this error message: ORA-00923: Schlüsselwort FROM nicht an erwarteter Stelle gefunden
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: @ElfoDerElf check now

Comment: still the same, i already saw that wrong AND and removed it :)

Comment: @ElfoDerElf https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4496ce28b44552d2431ad98018db56a5 check this link it works

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=971a424b8ac35f7e4080b02f83ad897c i corrected now the data so its the same as it is in my databse see the output from your query and from mine, but i cant get your query to work  :( i see now that it works correct but it does not work at my place :(

Comment: @ElfoDerElf why not working your place find that or share your created fiddle

Comment: i updated my question with the link please check now sorry for the bad examples

Comment: should be row_number() over(partition by  unit_artnr order by null)rn from ean https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=33b1e0300268936e1dba9d2019e2e2ca

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT ART.*, EAN.*, EAN.ARTNR "EAN_ARTNR"
 FROM SUCH.ART ART,(select distinct * from SUCH.EAN) EAN 
 WHERE ART.ARTNR = ean.unit_artnr
 and ean.typ = 'LE4' ;
```

Comment: this does not work, because there are multiple entries in ART and i need all of them but if i join EAN like i did it shows some ART entries doubled because there are 2 entries in EAN

Comment: please edit your post and include some sample data so I can help you more

Comment: this still gives me doubled entries

Comment: Try @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin solution then

Comment: i did but this doesnt go through

Comment: According to your sample data provided above @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin solution works just fine! I created your data and run his query against it and I got one row